# Exec. func as long as the left mouse button is held down (pure js)

Tags: javascript

For just a click I can do something like.

```
window.addEventListener("click", function(){console.log("Click detected!"},
false);
```

How do I call a func. repeatedly as long as the left mouse button is held down?

The way I am understanding is that `onmousedown` is for middle, left and right mouse so that's not a pointer in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `setInterval` that is then cleared on `mouseup`:

```js
function dolog() {
  console.log("Click detected!");
}
window.addEventListener("mousedown", (downe) => {
  if (downe.button !== 0) return;
  const interval = setInterval(dolog, 50);
  window.addEventListener("mouseup", (upe) => {
    if (upe.button === 0) clearInterval(interval);
  }, true, true);
});
```

You have to use the `mousedown` event rather than the `click` event because `click` gets fired when the mouse is *released*.

Comment: This executes it for all 3 buttons: left, mid and right. I want only the left button to exec. the func.

Answer (score 0):

`mousedown` doesn't occur repeatedly.

You can simulate that, using catch `mouseup` event and `mousedown` event.

```js
{
  let btn = document.querySelector( "input" );
  {
    let repeater;
    btn.addEventListener( "mousedown", event => {
      console.log( "down" );
      repeater = setInterval( button => console.log( "repeat", button ), 0, event.button );
    }, { capture: false } );
    btn.addEventListener( "mouseup", event => {
      console.log( "up" );
      clearInterval( repeater );
    }, { capture: false } );
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="mouse">
```